# How do I give webkitGetUserMedia permission in a Chrome Extension popup window?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrtc

I've successfully used webkitGetUserMedia to capture video from my webcam on a normal webpage, but when I try to do this in the popup.html of my Chrome Extension nothing happens. I don't get any permission errors, it just never even seems to ask (the inforbar never slides down in the popup window). Is there any way around this? It doesn't look like I can give permissions in the manifest json.

Comment: Hey, can you post your manifest.json file and the code that's in your popup.html. I believe this works, but I'd need to see what you're trying to do in order to help. I'm trying to do the same thing from a background page, but I can do it from a popup.

Answer (score 20):

It's a cheap hack, but if you create an options page for your extension and include a call to `webkitGetUserMedia` in the JS for it, it will request permission for all URIs for that extension, after the user allows it in the options page the background page will also have permission to use it.

Comment: This worked for me after days of searching for a solution!  tsbarnes rocks!

Comment: Works! but you need to get the user to access the options page

Comment: How exactly should you call webkitGetUserMedia? And what subsequent calls does that allow? Ideally, can you give example code? @gregoiregentil

Comment: Is this still relevant in 2014?

Comment: ...and even in 2018

Answer (score 6):

**Chrome Extensions and WebRTC:**

The [Chrome Extensions Manifest Permissions Documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) doesn't mention the two permissions needed in the manifest, "videoCapture" and "audioCapture", so I'm not sure if that functionality is available to Chrome Extensions or not, you should try and see what happens before continuing any further! ;)

**Chrome Packaged Apps and WebRTC:**

However, in Chrome Packaged apps, it is possible, both in sandboxed and non-sandboxed pages! Chrome Packaged Apps are very similar to extensions, so depending on what you're doing, you may want to build an app instead.

In the [Packaged Apps Manifest Permissions Documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions.html), the "videoCapture" and "audioCapture" permissions aren't explicitly listed, but one is demonstrated in an example.

I have a packaged app that uses a sandboxed HTML page to run webkitGetUserMedia, and it works great. Here is what you'd need in your manifest:

```
{
  "name": "app name",
  "version": "0.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "21",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    /* "128": "icon_128.png" */
  },
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": ["call.htm" ]
  },
  "permissions" : [ "videoCapture", "audioCapture" ]
}
```

You then need to launch your popup from the chrome://newtab page as an app. The main.js should contain something like this:

```
// Chrome v24+
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('mainpage.html',
        {width: 1190, height: 709});
});
```

And mainpage should be your popup window.  In my setup, I have an iframe called call.htm inside mainpage.html, and the iframe page is sandboxed so it can do some unsafe operations that can only be done as a normal web page. However, if I run the getUserMedia command in a non-sandboxed popup, I do get the MediaStream object from the call to webkitGetUserMedia:

```
 navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true },
                function (stream) {
                    mediaStream = stream;
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.error("Error trying to get the stream:: " + error.message);
                });
```

I tested it out, and I was able to capture my video in a popup.

Comment: Thanks for the details! Unfortunately it doesn't work with extensions:
"There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
'videoCapture' is only allowed for packaged apps, and this is a extension."

I've got an issue being on tracked on chromium, so hopefully they'll get this sorted out sooner rather than later.

Comment: There's not much difference between packaged app and extension. You might look into trying to create a page action or browser action, but as a packaged app. I may be wrong, but I think everything you'd want to do in an extension is available via the packaged apps api.  They even install the same way extensions do...

Comment: Here's the relevant bug for the extension permissions: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160337

Comment: Note: As of (at least) 2/17/2014, getUserMedia audio/video recording no longer require experimental permissions! Huzzah!

Comment: success to create this unsafe packaged app area and play mic :)

Comment: As far as I know, yo can't use browser or page actions from an app. Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @tsbarnes there is a hack but for Chrome apps the hack is different, you call navigator.webkitGetUserMedia from `background.js` instead, something like:

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function() {
    console.log('ok');
}, function(e) {
    console.log('webcam not ok');
});
```

And then you still can access audio/video from window.html or any other webview

Answer (score 0):

Asking for `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` in `options.js` works but you MUST open `option.html` popup in a NEW TAB or you will obtain an error so in the `manifest.json` you must to write

```
"options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true,
    "open_in_tab": true
  }
```