# Can the extension be given access to "videoCapture"?

Tags: javascript, plugins, webrtc

I want to give an extension access to "videoCapture". I do it like this

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "app",
    "description": "app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["app.js"],
        "run_at":"document_end"
      }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions" : [ "videoCapture" ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Аn error is thrown when launching the plugin: " 'videoCapture' is only allowed for packaged apps, but this is a extension. "
If you write a plugin like an application, then everything works. No mistakes!

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "app",
  "description": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["app.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    /* "128": "icon_128.png" */
  },
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": ["call.htm" ]
  },
  "permissions" : [ "videoCapture", "audioCapture" ]
}
```

Can you do the same in an extension?

Comment: Did you try running that error message through a search engine?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076272/how-do-i-give-webkitgetusermedia-permission-in-a-chrome-extension-popup-window

Comment: there this problem is solved by the fact that the packaged application is used